# Raspberry pi 4b with ADC Pi and capacitive moisture sensor

Tags: analog-to-digital

I recently bought the following

- https://thepihut.com/products/capacitive-soil-moisture-sensor
- https://thepihut.com/products/adc-pizero

Note: Raspberry pi 4 is not listed as compatible at Pihut, but it is compatible according to this site: https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/p/69/adc-pi-raspberry-pi-analogue-to-digital-converter

Admittedly, I am as new as it gets to physical computing. I have been reading and searching for a few days, but I am none the wiser. I cant find a user case equal to mine. All in all, I find few cases where ADC Pi is in use.

I have enabled i2c and prepared the RPi. Also familiarized myself with the GPIOs through buttons and lights.

In terms of connecting hardware, I have not tried much since I am afraid of ruining something due to lack of other use cases.

How do I set up the hardware in order to make the moisture sensor work? Any pointers is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The sensor simply says Raspberry Pi so either it’s a broad compatibly list or an old one

Comment: Please `EDIT` your question and indicate what you have done so far.

Comment: You need to connect up.  We can't walk you through the process (this is a Q&A site).  Use `i2cdetect -y 1` on the Pi to check the ADC is connected to the I2C bus properly.

Comment: Yeah. I realize that. Desperate attempt after hours of being clueless. Thank you.

Comment: For open ended problems you may get a more useful response at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/ as that site is more flexible in that respect.